# Representing Prolog knowledge base as a tree

Tags: prolog, logic

I'm meant to create a searching algorithm for a knowledge base. The KB is originally in the form of rules, for example:

```
a :- b, c.
a :- d
b.
d.
```

Which can be represented as the list `[[a,b,c], [a,d], [b], [d]]`. Or, it can be represented as a tree:

```
         [a]
          |
    -------------
    |           |
  [b,c]        [d]
    |           |
   [c]         [ ]
```

However, I don't understand the reasoning behind these representations. Is this a common abstraction that is used in Prolog? (I'm still new to it). A classmate told me that it can also be looked at as a FSM, where `[b,c]` and `[d]` are final states. But this doesn't seem to make sense either, since `[b,c]` has no child node, whereas `[d]` does.

Is there some consensus as to how the knowledge base can be represented/looked at? I have trouble finding the links between each representation, and what they mean. I apologize for the vagueness of my question, but I have such little knowledge of Prolog and knowledge bases that I'm not sure how to ask this. If it helps at all, this is a AI course. Any insight is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It all depends. What kind of queries will you be making on this data?

Comment: That tree is not a representation of the rules + facts, but a representation of the traditional topmost-first depth-first search tree of the "Prolog Processor" - an execution trace. To solve a, try b (success) then c (failure). Try a again, try d (success of search for a).

Comment: It's certainly not a FSM either, because Prolog is of course "Turing Complete", and more powerful than a FSM, as powerful as C (for example). Take a look at the idea behind the Prolog resolution mechanism (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution) and Unification (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(compute))

Comment: Also: [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy: Automated Reasoning - Resolution](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reasoning-automated/#Res)